# How to return a different active record based on some condition when an active record object is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Product model has id,name and master_prouduct_id

Products that has master_prouduct_id as NULL are master products themselves.

Whenver I load a product object I need to return the master_product.

How do I implement this?

I thought I could get this done through after_find callback.

But after_find is called after loading the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one simple way you can do is, having following relation in model

```
belongs_to :master_product, :foreign_key => : master_prouduct_id, :class_name => "Product"
```

by calling master_product on any product object we can get master object.

But this implementation needs application logic to handle whether to call master_product or not.

Don't worry, we can follow other way as below,

```
Product < AR::Base
    def self.find(id)
        rec = super(id)
        rec.master_product_id ? super(rec.master_product_id) : rec
    end
end
```

But, In this way we wont get the child products at all using find, even if we want to get child products also. So, i suggest to use different function name for this or have a flag in find definition it self to tell the requirement.

Still, You need to handle other scenarios(Where, Joins, Associations etc).

Iam not sure whether rails had any support for this.